# Mysql: Change set column on update condition?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to update one of two fields in a table.  I have a personrelationship table and it links two people and I would like to have each person be able to set the relationship type on their end.

PersonRelationship Table

```
id int
user1_id int
user2_id int
user1_reltype /* boss, manager, etc */
user2_reltype
```

Depending on whether the current user is either user1_id or user2_id in the table, I need to update the user_reltype accordingly.  So basically if current userid is in the user1_id field then update user1_reltype otherwise update the user2_reltype.

Comment: Do you have any sample data with your expected results from this? I believe their may be some way to use a `CASE` statement inside your update but it would help to have something to test with to make sure it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want each user to be able to independently manage their half of the relationship, you can simplify your table structure

```
--------------------------------------
| initiator_id | reltype | target_id |
```

When a person with ID 5 (the 'initiator') marks person with ID 9 (the 'target') as a friend, the table will contain:

```
---------------------------------------
| initiator_id | reltype  | target_id |
+--------------+----------+-----------+
|            5 | 'friend' |         9 |
```

If person 9 later initiates a 'boss' connection with person 5, the entry can be created without interfering with the row previously created by person 5:

```
--------------------------------------
| initiator_id | reltype | target_id |
+--------------+---------+_----------+
|            9 | 'boss'  |         5 |
```

This approach will make your table easy to read and your queries easy to write.

**Extra:**

If you do not already have it, consider creating another table to track relationship types ('reltype'):

```
-----------------
| id | type     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 'friend' |
|  2 | 'boss'   |
```

and replace the string reltype's in the relationship table with foreign keys.

```
---------------------------------------
| initiator_id | reltype  | target_id |
+--------------+----------+-----------+
|            5 |       1  |         9 |
|            9 |       2  |         5 |
```

Comment: My only concern with this approach is selecting a list of relationships for a user.  I would have to make sure to pull only one unique record because one relationship now is two rows.

Comment: If each end can manage the relationship type, won't every user have two potential relationships with every person? There's the one that they person initiates, and the "incoming" relationship from the other person.

Comment: I'm just thinking on how to avoid listing duplicates when I would pull the list of relationsips for a user.  Right now if I did a SELECT * FROM personrelationship WHERE initiator_id = :current_user OR target_id :current_user it would list a relationship twice.

Comment: Ah, I see. It may be that I misunderstand the use-case, but consider the example: If `:current_user` is '5', your query will pull two rows: One saying that 5 named 9 as a friend, and one saying that 9 named 5 as a boss. Is the goal of the query to produce a list of linked people (in which case only one result should be returned, no matter how many reltypes there are within the relationship) or is the goal to see how many total relationships link to person 5?

Comment: Yes, if the :current_user = 5, then I would like it to pull a list of people that user has a relationship with.  So it would only need to pull one row per relationship.